# Is it possible to say 'I forgot my key' instead of 'I left my key'?

Tags: grammar

I heard that it's not correct to say ' I forgot my key'. Could you tell me, is it possible to use such way of a sentence? P.S. I think the rules are changing, because time is changing and the language has developed today.

Comment: I've never heard that you are not supposed to say, "I forgot my key" (or any other item). It's actually a very common phrase, at least in American English.

Comment: What do you want the first sentence to mean? Did you leave your key in your room and went outside? What's the context?

Comment: Who says it's not correct? What reason do they give?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in meaning.  To leave something may be a deliberate act.

> I left my key on the table so my wife would find it when she came home.

But forgetting is normally unintentional:

> Oh no! I forgot my key. I hope my wife has a spare.

It would be slightly odd to say "I forgot my key on the table". As this implies both intentional and unintentional (the meanings are contradictory)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely fine to use "I forgot my key". If you want to use "I left my key", you need to add where you left it, or "behind", otherwise it is incomplete.

But "forgot" is (and always has been as far as I am aware) totally correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!